# Google Earth Engine asset quota

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript

I am trying to upload 317 images to GEE to create an image collection to analyze its time series.  After about 250 it stopped ingesting and I received the error message: "Error: Exceeded quota for total asset size: using 250.95GiB of 250.00GiB"

Should I create another image collection and merge them, or would that not work? How can I get around this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've reached the total size quota limit for your account. Accounts are limited to 250 GB of space and 10,000 assets. You can check on account limits and status from the Asset Manager tab in the Code Editor—see the second paragraph of the Developer Guide's page on [Managing Assets](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/asset_manager).

An alternative option that provides more space for images is Google Cloud Storage. You can upload cloud optimized GeoTIFFs (COGs) into a bucket and access them from Earth Engine. For an example, see the [Images from Cloud GeoTIFFs](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/image_overview?hl=en#images-from-cloud-geotiffs) section of the Developer's Guide.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.  I did push my images over from a Google Cloud Storage bucket, but I was not aware of the ability to cloud optimize them.  Good to know in the future :)